# KDE or GNOME? Which one to choose?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, kde, kubuntu

I would like to switch from window to linux?
Which one should I choose? Ubuntu/Kubuntu or something else?
I'm a **LAMP based developer.**
Which one will be better for me? **KDE or GNOME**

Comment: Well, KDevelop would be an argument for KDE, but then again if you have the KDEBase libraries I think you can run KDevelop on Gnome, so it probably doesn't matter. At all. In fact, you could probably use just enlightenment or fluxbox or something if you're comfortable with some command-line stuff now and then...

Comment: Sounds more like a question for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Subjective and argumentative. Bring real criteria. Besides, it's just your window manager, you can probably flip a coin.

Comment: I agree with Daniel. These are user interfaces with no real requirements for software. When it comes down to it, you can run anything in either UI, the UI you use is based on what you're comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

This has possibly changed, but from a resources perspective the best I remember is that Gnome consumed more resources than KDE. Depending on the hardware you are using you might want to take that into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Whichever one you like more. You can install the libraries side-by-side and use KDE applications in Gnome and Gnome applications in KDE. Using both uses a bit more memory, but if you're trying to run this on a router or something, then I would use neither ;)

You might try asking for suggestions for good PHP/Perl/Python editors and tools (depending on what the 'P' in your 'LAMP' stands for), and armed with that knowledge reassess which environment would be more productive to you if there is some reason that you cannot run both.

Answer (score 0):

KDE tends to be more customizable out of the box than Gnome has been--more options are exposed in the GUI than with Gnome.

Then again, Gnome has been more stable than KDE over the past year or so, as a result of KDE's growing pains.